# Normals of Mesh is in correct in Face Orientation but wrong in Quixel Mixer and UE4

Tags: export, faces, normals

So my mesh in Blender 2.8 is shown to be correctly oriented, but when imported into Quixel Mixer or UE4, it's the opposite.

I tried to simply flip the normals but it didn't really work well with textures in Mixer so I was hoping for another way.

I also read a post that said if I were to export it as a .dae, it would fix the issue, but I have had no luck with this.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Blender[image]

Quixel Mixer [image]

Comment: i had this issue too and fixed with "recalculate" Shading/UV > Shading > Normals > Recalculate

Comment: Hey @AkaiShuichi, I tried that but by going through Edit Mode > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside but it didn't fix the issue either. I can't seem to find the Shading/UV tab.